# Range of lines in file

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep, perl

I have a file with a few o lines:

```
  C   1.31729690416596     -0.05166770188922      0.05026556004853
  C   2.15676687192808     -0.87605403673920      0.93010807487406
  C   1.45516592682388     -0.49804136618225     -1.24011085742027
  C   2.67489108786199     -2.06116694592319      0.09667460087481
  C   2.24626744432148     -1.81826783081380     -1.24626795859707
  C   0.12278380551129     -0.78127661791244     -1.79035714840462
  C   0.11627012096698     -2.05095769577445     -2.31049614254010
  C   1.41908665901196     -2.77247309785857     -1.91624359298119
```

I need to print in one operation a complex range of lines, for intance line 1 more lines 4 to 7, this is 1,4-7. How to get those lines instead of searching each.

Comment: Are non-ordered and repeated values or ranges like `3,2,1-3` allowed?

Comment: What is the issue that you have with solving this? Why have you added the`awk`, `sed`, `grep` and `perl` tags to this question? Are these tools that you are already using to try to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>ed</kbd> line editor:

```
printf '%s\n' '1p' {4..7}p 'Q' | ed -s - file
```

---

<kbd>awk</kbd>:

```
printf 'NR==%d\n' 1 {4..7} | awk -f - file
```

---

<kbd>sed</kbd> stream editor:

```
printf '%sp\n' 1 4,7 | sed -nf - file
```

---

<kbd>perl</kbd>:

```
perl -lne 'print if grep { $_ == $. } (1, 4..7)' file
```

Comment: Simpler `sed` command - `echo "1p; 4,7p" | sed -nf - file`

Comment: thanks for giving a better alternative. it is incorporeal in the solution.

Comment: Thanks!!! Perl option resolved my issue. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

With `awk` using `NR` var:

```
awk 'NR == 1 ||  NR >= 4 && NR <= 7' file
  C   1.31729690416596     -0.05166770188922      0.05026556004853
  C   2.67489108786199     -2.06116694592319      0.09667460087481
  C   2.24626744432148     -1.81826783081380     -1.24626795859707
  C   0.12278380551129     -0.78127661791244     -1.79035714840462
  C   0.11627012096698     -2.05095769577445     -2.31049614254010
```

Answer (score 0):

command

```
sed -n -e '1p' -e '4,7p' filename
```

output

```
 C   1.31729690416596     -0.05166770188922      0.05026556004853
  C   2.67489108786199     -2.06116694592319      0.09667460087481
  C   2.24626744432148     -1.81826783081380     -1.24626795859707
  C   0.12278380551129     -0.78127661791244     -1.79035714840462
  C   0.11627012096698     -2.05095769577445     -2.31049614254010
```